# A different way to treat thoughtful 'Opinion based' questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, opinion-based

I've been on Stack Overflow for a bit, and getting questions closed is still very painful to me. 'Primarily opinion based' especially rubs me the wrong way, because the most interesting questions often *are* somewhat subjective and don't have a definite answer. This is not just 'Which framework is best?'. I see this happening with thoughtful questions, that simply don't have a single correct answer, or questions that wonder how to 'broadly tackle a problem'.

An issue with this is that questions that just have a very small hint of subjectivity are picked off by people with close privileges. While I'm 4 paragraphs into an answer, it feels like a moderator might spend a few seconds reading the question and decides it's not worthy; preventing me from even hitting the submit button. It's especially painful if I've invested significant time into what I believe is a thoughtful reply.

All this made me wonder if there's a better way. Treating subjective questions as a legitimate question is probably not going to happen (as I'm sure there have been many discussions about this before), but perhaps we can't be outright expelled from using the site or interacting with each other. I've even pondered in past situations if I could find OP's contact information and email them instead, as I'm genuinely invested at this point.

Perhaps questions can simply be flagged as subjective. This flag might prevent the question from showing up in search results, or even indexed, but it doesn't prevent me from having a potentially great interaction with someone else.

This is not a fully fleshed-out idea, but I would more broadly ask... is there a better way to treat high-quality questions that don't exactly fit the Stack Overflow mold. The message I'm getting right now is: "We don't want you here, and we're censoring you". I'm hoping there might be less aggressive, more welcoming solutions to this?

Comment: just a, minor note on the "closed while writing an answer" bit, you can un-disable the submit button and submit it anyway, if you were in progress of writing it. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the actual problem and is more of just a quick fix to be rarely used.

Comment: Flagging (for lack of a better term) a question as subjective doesn't really solve the primary reason that close reason exists. The subjective questions it is meant for are questions where the answers are 100% based on personal opinion and are likely to become irrelevant or wrong on a short time-scale. For example, which build-process library is best for javascript. We've been through at least 4 different "best" in the recent past. IMO, questions that don't fall into that trap should probably be able to get by without that close reason

Comment: @KevinB I didn't know you could un-disable it, thanks! I also understand your sentiment regarding 'which build process is best'. It falls in the same category as 'Which framework is best' which imho is not a good question.

Comment: (digging through your answers) the most recent question you answered that was closed for this reason could probably have been rewritten to avoid the subjective close reason, but I'm sure it's a duplicate

Comment: @KevinB that answer triggered me from writing this, although it's probably not the best example. I've had more than a few situations like this that were even more brutal.

Comment: All the downvotes here seems pretty aggressive! I thought that those were primarily used to indicate quality issues with question, not disagreeing... so I'm curious if people can elaborate?

Comment: Yep, it is an interesting question, and one with good answers, but the best (lol) case scenario is solving it for a given transform library, like babel for example, and that would never fall under subjective

Comment: There's definitely a larger conversation to be had here about the closure of questions which are only borderline subjective on SO... I think a lot of curators pounce too quickly on questions with subjective language, and ignore that 1) a question which can be rephrased in an objective manner usually shouldn't be closed and 2) a *lot* of on-topic questions are actually subjective, since there are many ways to solve most programming problems. We're inconsistent and fickle; I would still say that most people seem to know a great question when they see one though.

Comment: Related, from the SO Blog: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: Downvotes on meta are the opposite tbh, they don't affect rep and are primarily for showing disagreement (of course they also indicate quality issues; but the quality of your question is fine ;)

Comment: @Yatin thank you, good to know. I was getting super stressed out, not gonna lie.

Comment: If you want to discuss an issue that doesn't fit well with SO's policy of acceptable questions, you can discuss it in chat, either an existing room where the issue is related to the main topic of the chat room, if you think the issue would be of interest to the room. Or just create a new room for the discussion. Of course, that requires the OP to have sufficient rep (20 points) to write in chat rooms.

Comment: It's very hard for me to be sympathetic here, because I just haven't noticed very many questions getting closed as "primarily opinion-based" that I don't think are precisely that. And, specifically, of the type where the asker is just seeking to start a discussion, there is no right answer, there is no objective criteria to judge the correctness of answers, etc. I would be very interested to see some specific examples of questions that you think would be a good fit for Stack Overflow, yet got closed for this reason. I'll admit, the reason *is* ripe for misunderstanding and thus misapplication.

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough, that would certainly explain the luke-warm response here. Perhaps it's just something I run into.

Comment: @zcoop98: _"I think a lot of curators pounce too quickly on questions with subjective language"_ Honestly, I've caught myself doing this while reviewing _opinion-based_ flags in the _Close Votes_ queue—even when I find the question useful (e.g., "Why is this considered an anti-pattern? How else would I solve this?"). There are certain trigger words (e.g., "best practice", "better", "which", even "why") that indicate subjectivity, but either a) could be rewritten to be more objective, or b) fall into [the carve-out for subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @zcoop98: It's worth noting that while [the blog post you referenced on asking good subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) is a decade old, it continues to be referenced from the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and is thus, presumably, current guidance. As I often filter the _Close Votes_ queue by _opinion-based_ flags, it's something I need to slow down and be more conscientious about. Sometimes I get stuck in "Can I justify this vote?" instead of "Can I salvage this question?"

Answer (score 8):

> Perhaps questions can simply be flagged as subjective. This flag might prevent the question from showing up in search results, or even indexed, but it doesn't prevent me from having a potentially great interaction with someone else.

Then what's the point in answering it at all? Just close it, downvote it, delete the question and be done with it.

**The goal of Stack Overflow is simple. Maintain a repository of useful questions and answers so that people having the same problem can search for it and find the solution to the problem.** If the question is subjective and there can't be one correct solution, then it doesn't fit on Stack Overflow. Such questions belong on Reddit, Quora, Yahoo or some place else.

> We don't want you here, and we're censoring you

If by "you" you mean the question, then you are absolutely correct. We don't want such questions here. However, we want the user to ask better questions. Ones that will actually benefit the community.

Nobody is saying that you can't ask such questions at all. Just don't do it here.

Comment: I understand that some people such as yourself don't want me here, although I'm surprised to see it stated so clearly and without empathy. This does sadly reflect my experience here quite well.

Comment: @Evert But this answer explicitly says that they don't want the *questions* of the kind that you've mentioned above, not that they don't want *you* as a user.

Comment: @Evert I think you are reading what you want to read. That is **not** what this answer says. At all.

Comment: Feels like this is similar to my answer with a slightly gentler tone.  It's still a useful answer and the general thrust is pretty much the same; we're not interested in unsuitable *questions*, but we hold no opinion of you as a person in relation to those questions.

Comment: @Evert We want you here. We really want you to help out on this site. We just don't want unhelpful questions

Comment: @Dharman, thank you. I did read something more negative than it was. It's good to know that at least on the meta.stackoverflow side it seems fairly universal that there's no interest in a friendlier way to treat these kind of questions.

Comment: [They don't belong on Yahoo anymore](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN35642.html)...

Answer (score 3):

This statement is a paradox.  (Emphasis mine)

> [I]s there a better way to treat **high-quality questions** that **don't [...] fit the Stack Overflow mold**.

If a question doesn't fit our mold, then how can it be considered high quality versus **all of the other good questions which do?**

It's very much the case that the ***company*** doesn't do a good job of explaining that questions are welcome on the Exchange network if they follow the rules of the individual communities, and we get this feeling of "unwelcomeness" that seems to be associated with, "Well, what if we just bent the rules a *little* to..."

Using this as premise:

> The message I'm getting right now is: "We don't want you here, and we're censoring you".

We're *not* sending that message, but there's little we can do to change that you're *receiving* that message without drastically changing our standards of quality, which is non-negotiable.

Comment: "If a question doesn't fit our mold, then how can it be considered high quality versus all of the other good questions which do".

This suggest to me that a question that is not appropriate for stack overflow must by nature be low quality. That that a change in how these questions are treated would by definition be a reduction of quality. In other words, everything already works great and by design and a change is not needed. Is that an accurate summary?

Comment: It turns into a problem of scale, @Evert.  Anyone can ask any kind of question, which for some communities is okay, but for Stack Overflow - over the last decade-plus, the site has become more and more strict about the kinds of questions which get asked here.  We still get wave after wave of bad question or obvious "do my work" questions, and it's still the case that we get those kinds of open-ended, any-answer-could-be-right kinds of questions.  **We need to avoid that** simply to make content moderation even feasible.

Comment: Any change to that then changes the level of quality we want to accept here, @Evert.  If suddenly now we're OK with open-ended questions then now we have to kind of re-teach the dedicated few of us who still moderate on how to deal with those kinds of questions.  That doesn't happen overnight.  What would be *easier* would be to explain and make clear what we're willing to accept as opposed to try to get us to bend over backwards to accept what one is giving us.

Comment: It's definitely not a perfect system; there's a lot over the years that the community has suggested for its improvements and maybe a few things that the company has bothered to implement.  But largely, @Evert, it's the system we have to keep Stack Overflow at least somewhat sane or simple to navigate.  It's also the value we've provided to the site which let it be sold for so many billions.

Comment: I am 100% with you on low-quality, do-my-home-work style questions. That's not the category of questions I want to discuss. I also respect that change is very difficult and perhaps unrealistic. I'm not expecting a miracle, or want to disrespect people's hard work =). At a minimum, perhaps I'm seeking acknowledgement or validation for an issue I'm experiencing as someone who's also spent countless hours producing content here and trying to make this place better in my own way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  If one wants to write open-ended, subjective questions, forums exist.  If one wants an answer to their concrete questions, Stack Overflow exists.  You can find validation from either, but neither is obliged to tolerate just *any* ol' question that comes their way.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think 'any ol' question' is an intellectually honest interpretation of what I've written.

Comment: @Makoto Just to interject, the idea that open-ended, subjective questions are categorically unfit for SO openly contradicts guidance in the help center; we have very clear criteria for what a high-quality, on-topic subjective question needs to look like on SO. It's summed up on the lower half of [this help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and described at length in the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). No one's proposing "anything goes" here.

Comment: @zcoop98: It's been **a while** since I've seen a good subjective question.  Quite a number of them try but quite a number of them fall flat on their face when paired with some level of scrutiny.  Maybe if I saw some specific examples, I'd be swayed, but without explicit examples it's tough for me to move from my position.